# Реализация spinner-loader AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

привет хочу реализовать loader
делаю так
контроллер

```
app.controller('ctrl',  function($scope, $location, httpQuery, initData){
    $scope.loader = initData.loader;
    $scope.movie = httpQuery.getLastUpdate();
    $scope.beginView = function(id, g) {
        $location.path('/selected/' + id + '/' + g);
    }
});
```

фабрика

```
app.factory('initData', function() {
    return{
        loader: true
    }
});
```

В запросе я переменой из фабрики присваиваю false

```
app.factory('httpQuery', function($http, initData){
    return{
        getLastUpdate: function(){
            var lastFilm = [];
            $http.get('http://localhost:51265/Home/GetLastAdded').then(function(response){
                for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
                    lastFilm.push(response.data[i]);
                }
            })
            .finally(function () {
                alert(initData.loader);
                initData.loader = false;
                alert(initData.loader);
            });
            return lastFilm;
        }
    }
});
```

если верить алертам то оно меняется.
Но проблема в том что при запуске приложения спинер на долю секунды появится и потом исчезает

html код

```
<div>
                <div class="loader" ng-show="loader">

                </div>
                <div class="mid-panel" ng-view>

                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: ты уже понял, что в `$scope.loader = initData.loader;` ты сохранил значение, а не ссылку?

Comment: не не понял еще